# How to use Shared Components static files or CSS files on a page html region APEX ( Oracle Application Express)

Tags: javascript, html, css, oracle-apex, static-files

I have uploaded javascript files and a CSS file in shared component. I want to use these files in a HTML region I am trying to build. I need to use these files from shared component. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used APEX, and looking at their [region documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21674/ui_region.htm) you need to make sure you know which type of HTML region you're editing.

In short, though, you can use the `<link>` and `<script>` tags to use data from external files.

**CSS**

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="path/to/styles.css" />`

The `<script>` tag is similar. You need to be sure to call the function somewhere in your HTML.

**Script**

`<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/javascript.js"></script>`

Comment: Dats true Brian. I am editing in "HTML Text" region. I have added <script src="APP_IMAGES#jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and <link rel="stylesheet" href="#APP_IMAGES#iThing.css" type="text/css"> in "HTML Header" of the page. But when i write some code in html text region those scripts or files are not being used. Where am i going wrong or how should i use these files in the html region..

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing the uploaded file path correctly?

Comment: Thats the thing i worry.. How to check that.. I am using the same code http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/documentation.html#quickStart given here. Would the referencing be wrong.. If it is, then what is the right way.

Comment: I have no idea...it depends on the architecture of APEX and how they handle file uploads.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.
You have to include script references in page definition header only. 
At html text region, you need not have to include scripts or css files. They are to be included in page dfinition. & path for it  would  be ``` "<script src="APP_IMAGES#jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">" ``</script> and <link rel="stylesheet" href="#APP_IMAGES#iThing.css" type="text/css">  / em would  be <script src="APP_IMAGES#jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and <link rel="stylesheet" href="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#iThing.css" type="text/css"> or likewise ```